# Ember.js (pre4) array controller not keeping state

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

**Edit 2013-03-02**

This appears to be resolved in RC1

---

In previous versions of Ember.js, controllers would keep state assigned to them, but this seems to be an issue in Pre4.

So if I were to have this controller

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: ['mike', 'jen', 'sofia'],

    _content_observer: (function(){
         /* I'm called, but my author doesn't know why */
         console.log('Content was altered! But why? And by whom?');
    }).observes('content')
});
```

The content is overwritten for some unexplained reason. I **don't want to use ember data**, but it seems like I'm being forced that direction.

This [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/XSZZW/) exemplifies the issue.

What's going on? How do I stop it or is this so engrained in embers opinionatedness that I need to just accept it and go with the flow?

---

**Edit**

Taking this a bit further, it appears that whatever is setup as the `model` will be set to the `content` value, even if you override the `setupController` hook.

e.g.:

```
UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        /*I should never be called, but I am. How curious.*/
        return ['This','Shouldnt','Be','Assigned'];
    },
    setupController: function() {
        /* According to http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/, I should prevent the model from being assigned to content, but I don't */
    }
});
```

The `UsersController.content` will end up with the value `['This','Shouldnt','Be','Assigned']`

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/dz98R/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an ember-data thing. The new router sets controller's content property automatically. Instead of setting content from within the controller dedinition, customize the model that will be used for your route by overriding the model hook. For example:

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return ['mike', 'jen', 'sofia', 'greta']
    }
}
```

I modified your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WGYmg/

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was editing when you replied. This functionality is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The array controller for my actual project for users is loading its content via ajax and therefore setting up the model that way doesn't work in practice. I need to be able to have the `content` loaded via ajax after an observer triggers it to happen.

Comment: The problem with this is that whatever is in the `model` function is executed synchronously and stored somewhere and I don't have a way to update or change it. I've tried `this.set('model')` from within an observer on the controller, but to no avail.

Comment: Seems the guide is causing some confusion. When it says "You can change this behavior by implementing the setupControllers hook" it means you can customize controller's content from there, but overriding setupController does not prevent model callback.

Comment: Also, the model callback is designed to work with async code, the use case you describe (lookup via ajax) is exactly how ember-data works. Updating my answer to provide some more guidance.

Comment: great! I look forward to that. I wouldn't even be opposed to learning and using ember data, but there are no docs on making a custom adapter. just vague references that it can be done. unfortunately the restful adapter won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `setupController` method to set the controller's contents as you like:

```js
setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('content', []);
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz98R/3/)

#### Edit

You can use the `model` method to return the original content:

```js
model: function () {
    var c = this.controllerFor('users');
    return c.get('content');
}
```

This is a bit hackish, but still..:)

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz98R/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point is for `content` not to get overwritten at all, not to set it from the Route.

Comment: I think that the `setupController` is the place where you initialize things - that's the way ember works. The initial value of `content` is somewhat negligible..

Comment: `setupController` is called everytime you are routed to that controller, so it that were the case then you would be re-initializing everything every time you visit the controller. That would mean that you'd be expected to make the ajax call, process the response, and populate the contente every time... That's ridiculous.

Comment: on setting the model (from your edit) with the content, I've actually tried that, but the content is blank when the model grabs it. The ajax loads later and populates the content. Then the content is wiped when the user navigates to it.

Comment: I think that the ember way is that the controller is reinitialized each time you visit the route. This includes setting the model. If you use _ember-data_, it will use cached result thus saving ajax call, but you still will need to repopulate the content. Fortunately, ember dos this automatically.

Comment: Given how it is coded, it seems that you are right, at least with this revision of ember. It is a fast moving target. In previous builds, I had gotten quite comfortable with the fact that I could initialize my controllers and they wouldn't be messed with.

Comment: There is  an `ApplicationController`, which will not change as long as you stay within current application.. You may intialize it and store there all the data which you don't want to be messed with..